# Year : Anniversary :: Day : ___?___

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a term for a milestone number of days since an event, just as an anniversary is a milestone (in increments of years)?

I want to say “100 day-versary” or something like that.

Comment: In practice, _anniversary_ is not necessarily measured in increments of years, despite its Latin meaning. High school sweethearts frequently celebrate their two-month anniversary (and then break up a week later because teenagers). I don’t think many people would bat even a single eyelash at “100-day anniversary”.

Comment: Today I learned this appears to be [a particularly Korean thing](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=100+day+anniversary). However, misusing the term is so common that it appears that no alternative exists. Presumably it would be a *dieversary,* but because of how that word looks it's bound to be mispronounced and misunderstood.

Comment: I don't think these are exact duplicates, but very relevant: [Is there a term for an anniversary that falls on the same day of the week as its original date?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/42058/177853) and [1000 Day “Anniversary”](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/129878/177853). The OP of the second question liked "kiloversary" and "k-day"; you might like "centiversary" or "c-day" (or "hectoversary/h-day" if you shudder when you hear "C-note" meaning a hundred dollar bill rather than a penny).

Comment: Latin prefixes! If "Annus" is for year, then "Dies" (DEE-es) is for day. So . . . dieversary?

Comment: @AndrewLeach For others’ sake, the “100-day anniversary” is a Korean thing, but not my intent. That was just an example on my part. My wife and I have been together 2048 days today, which is 2^11 days, or 10000000000 days in binary. I’m just a sentimental geek. :-)

Comment: I've too often heard people - particularly women - speak of their 'six-month…" or even "one-month anniversary" and the more clingy they appear, the more they seem happy to use "anniversary" as though it meant "commemoration" with no reference to time.

How long before they create an idiom?